# How can I change the maxlength validation for a text input based on a radio button selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have three radio buttons on my page, and a text input:

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
    <label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="Name" checked>Search By Name </label>
    <label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="City">Search By City </label>
    <label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="Code">Search By code </label>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <span class="row-fluid">
        <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" />
        <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to validate the length of the input on txtSearch based on the selected radio button, as the database fields are different lengths for those columns:

**Updated:**

```
$("#frmSearch").validate({
    debug: false,
    rules: {
        'txtSearch': {
            required: true,
            maxlength: function () {
                var sel = $('input[name=optionsRadios]:checked', '#frmSearch').val();

                if (sel == 'City') {
                    return 25;
                }
                else {
                    return 50;
                }
            },
            minlength: 2
        }
    }
});
```

I put the alerts in to tell me the lengths of the values, and all the alerts return what I expect, but the validation message displayed on every entry, no matter the length, is "Please enter no more than 1 characters."

Comment: I tried just returning the int, but from what I've read, "depends" only returns a boolean. Further, when I change it to just do a `if (sel == 'Name') { return 50; }`, I still only get the message "Please enter no more than 1 characters."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `depends` and replace with this:

```
maxlength: (function(){
                var sel = $('input[name=optionsRadios]:checked', '#frmOfficeSearch').val();

                if (sel == 'Name') {
                    return 50;
                }

                if (sel == 'City') {
                    return 25;
                }

                if (sel == 'Code') {
                    return 50;
                }

               })()
```

This creates a self executing function that returns the correct integer based on the selected radio.

Comment: I updated to just do the returns - still fails. Just gives the "Please enter no more than 1 characters." message. (I also updated the above code to reflect this.)

Comment: @PKD, try this new approach.

Comment: That led me in the right direction. The syntax was a teeny bit wonky, but I fixed it up. Accepting this as the answer, and posting the completed code above.